# How to handle Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, exceptionhandler, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have a script that process millions of data. Same data are corrupted, thus the framework I use is fail and throws exception. I am dependent to a framework that I cannot change/update. I have use it as it is. Every time I use function of this framework I use try/catch. Therefore, I am using lots of try/catch blocks as a result the code become unreadable I want to get rid of try/catch and handle exceptions separately from my code.

I want o have a global exception handler so whenever framework throws Exception it should catch and log and the loop that process data should be continue. There are web frameworks like spring and jersey which have a global exception handler. I want similar behaviour for script.

I tried Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler but the default behavior of UncaughtExceptionHandler is stop the process when exception occurred so it is not worked.

Currently my code looks like this. I want to get rid of try/catch blocks.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FrameworkException {
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(); //Millons of data
    processItems(elements)
}

public void processItems(List<Element> items) throws FrameworkException{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        try{
            framework.doSomething(elements.get(i));
        }
        catch(FrameworkException e){
            // handle
        }

        // . . .

        try{
            framework.doDifferentThing(elements.get(i));
        }
        catch(FrameworkException e){
            // handle
        }

        // . . .
    }

    System.out.println("Processing completed.");
}
```

My dream code and exceptions are handled in globally.

```
public void processItems(List<Element> items) throws FrameworkException{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            framework.doSomething(elements.get(i));

            // . . .

            framework.doDifferentThing(elements.get(i));

             // . . .
    }
    System.out.println("Processing completed.");
}
```

Comment: *"it should catch and log and the loop that process data should be continue"* - Then it sounds like you want to catch and handle the exception inside the loop.  Which you appear to already be doing.  Can you clarify in what way your attempt isn't working as expected?

Comment: I am using lots of try/catch blocks as a result the code become unreadable I want to get rid of try/catch and handle exceptions separately from my code.

Comment: If you want to catch and handle the exception within the loop then to do that you'd need to catch and handle the exception within the loop.  If the problem is that you have too many try/catch blocks within that loop then... Why do you have so many?  What are they doing differently from one another?  Have you tried to combine them?  Do you essentially have *working* code and are just looking for suggestions on how to refactor and reduce it?

Comment: @KaanAteşel you can't "remove all separate handling" AND handle them all "separately". But what is stopping you from having one simple try-catch block?

Comment: If all you're doing is logging the exception and continuing the loop, then why not just have a single try-catch?

Comment: I have to log different object in each try catch. I will try to combine them once again thank you for you answers.

Comment: Note that a single `try` can have multiple `catch`.

Comment: If `framework.doSomething(elements.get(i));` throws an exception, do you still want to try and call `framework.doDifferentThing(elements.get(i));` on the same object? Or do you want to stop processing that object the moment _any_ exception is thrown and proceed to the next object?

Comment: I want to stop processing the element and move on to the next one. For example in a web frameworks like spring or jersey there is a global exception handler I want similar kind of exception handling.

Comment: @KaanAteşel: "Global" would be *outside the loop*.  If you want to handle exceptions *inside* the loop then you'd do that *inside* the loop.  It sounds like you're just misunderstanding how exceptions and the call stack in general work.

Comment: @David thanks for you responses I will do a additional research.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a single `try`-`catch` block inside the loop, starting from the line immediately following the `for` statement (i.e. your whole loop is one big try-catch).

Comment: The exception is an extraordinary behaviour. Without it is not imaginable to create a program. There should be a global exception handler to catch all unchecked exceptions if you don't you program to exit. Otherwise it is bad to avoid any exception especially if it is checked one.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail "I have to log different object in each try catch."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a functional interface to represent actions performed on any `Element` that might throw a `FrameworkException`. Then, you just need to implement a method that accepts both the action and the current item. This method both encapsulates the try-catch logic and applies the action to the item.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ElementAction {
  void execute(Element element) throws FrameworkException;
}
```

```java
public void tryAction(ElementAction action, Element element) {
  try {
    action.execute(element);
  } catch (FrameworkException e) {
    // do whatever you usually do for exceptions
  }
}
```

This way you can have your `processItems` be cleaner like this:

```java
public void processItems(List<Element> items) {
  for (Element item : items) {
    tryAction(element -> framework.doSomething(item), item);

    // . . .

    tryAction(element -> framework.doDifferentThing(item), item);

    // . . .
    }

    // cont.
}
```

edit(just read the comments on the main post):

You can extend the `tryAction` method by passing in a `BiConsumer` that takes in an `Element` and a `FrameworkException` for custom loggin.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExceptionLogger extends BiConsumer<Element, FrameworkException> {}
```

You would then add it to the `tryAction` method:

```java
public void tryAction(ElementAction action, Element element, ExceptionLogger logger) {
  try {
    action.execute(element);
  } catch (FrameworkException e) {
    logger.accept(element, e);
  }
}
```

Then in your `processItems` you would add your way of logging the exception:

```java
public void processItems(List<Element> items) {
  for (Element item : items) {
    tryAction((
      element -> framework.doSomething(item), 
      item,
      (element, e) -> System.err.println("this error " + e.getMessage())
    );

    // . . .

    tryAction(
      element -> framework.doDifferentThing(item),
      item,
      (element, e) -> System.err.println("that error " + e.getMessage())
    );

    // . . .
    }

    // cont.
}
```

(this is assuming you are using Java 8+, which you really should be these days)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the loop to continue whenever a framework exception occurs:

```
for (Element item : items) {
    try {
        framework.doSomething(item);

        // ...

        framework.doDifferentThing(item);
    } catch (FrameworkException | SomeOtherFrameworkException e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Corrupted element " + item, e);
    }
}
```

This allows your logic to appear continuous, without being visually broken up by multiple `catch` blocks.

You should not be seeking to use some magical annotation to hide try/catch blocks from other developers.  Spreading out your logic into other places without any reference to them would just make future maintenance dramatically more difficult.

In this case, though, I don’t think there would be any way to do it, regardless.  You have to catch an exception if you want to recover from it and continue the loop.